# Workflow Foundation BRE missing Regex

Tags: regex, workflow-foundation, business-rules

I'm using WF BRE and try to use regex in rule condition. But there is no regex. The namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions does not exist, neither the Regex.Match method. 
I tried to add:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

to my Rules Designer Application but that didn't work.

I get the "**Rule Set Editor: Error parsing the Action(s): The identifier "Regex" could not be resolved.**" error.

How can I add regex to BRE?

Comment: @stribizhev Reference to System is added. I can't add reference to System.Text or System.Text.RegularExpressions.

Comment: @stribizhev as I wrote before, there is reference to System. You can't add there reference to System.Text or anything below that.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same issue. This is how I resolved it.

Created a method on class that entere the flow

```
public bool CheckPattern(string pattern, string value)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        return regex.IsMatch(value);
    }
```

And in Rule entered:

```
this.CheckPattern("myRegexPattern", myEmail)
```